# US2009/0183782 is the same as US2014/0048148, is that allowed?

Tags: prior-art

I came across two applications for the same thing, are you allowed to do this. Wouldn't the 2009 be considered prior art?

Answer (score 3):

I went on to PUBLIC PAIR and checked the status of both applications. US2009/0183782 was abandoned on 2-10-2014 in response to a non-final office action. US2014/0048148 was filed as a continuation-in- part of 2009/0183782 (meaning new information was added to the application) on 10-25-2013. So there is only one application covering the subject matter being examined by the USPTO. Since the 2014 application cites the 2009 in its continuity chain, the inventors have properly filed and 2009 will not be cited as prior art.